# PHP extracting getElementsByTagName from childNodes

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, getelementsbytagname, child-nodes

This should all be very straight forward but for some reason it is escaping me.

Using the following XML structure imported from a file:

```
<locations>
  <devices>
    <entry>
      <serial>12345</serial>
      <hostname>FooBarA</hostname>
      <vsys>
        <entry>
          <displayname>CorpA</displayName>
          <tag>InternalA</tag>
        </entry>
      </vsys>
      </c>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <serial>123456</serial>
      <hostname>FooBarB</hostname>
      <vsys>
        <entry>
          <displayname>CorpB</displayName>
          <tag>InternalB</tag>
        </entry>
      </vsys>
      </c>
    </entry>
  </devices>
</locations>
```

And extracting Parent  and  should be straight forward:

```
$devices = $dom->getElementsByTagName('devices');
$data = array();
foreach($devices as $node){  // each $node = <devices> == only ONE object
  foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {  // each $child is the ENTIRE <entry>, including <entry> tag
    // I would expect this to return the <serial> out of parent <entry>, but its not
    $serial = $child->getElementsByTagName('serial') ;
    echo "\n" . $count++ . ", a" .$serial->nodeName ;    
    if ($child->nodeName == "entry") {
      // as a secondary method, I then try to extra <serial> looping through the childNodes of the parent <entry> and again, this doesn't work.
      foreach ($child->childNodes as $kid) {
        $serial = $kid->getElementsByTagName('serial') ;
        echo ", b" .$serial->nodeName ;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above prints out:

```
1a, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b
2a, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b
3a, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b
4a, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b
```

My actual xml file has a lot more siblings at the `serial` level thus its printing out all the extra `b`s...thus that is telling me the basic foreach's are working and each is properly looping through each level - but I am not able to extract the nodeName or getElementsByTagName within each level.

I figured one of the two methods, at different nested levels, would have extracted `<serial>` but neither is working.  What am I missing here?

My expectation is it would print:

```
1a 12345, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b
2a 123456, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b
3a 1234567, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b
4a 12345678, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b
```

Or at a miniumum:

```
1a, b 12345, b 12345, b 12345 ...
2a, b 123456, b 123456, b 123456 ...
3a, b 1234567, b 1234567, b 1234567 ...
etc etc.
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: $child->childNodes 
$node->childNodes  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), so you need to iterate it to get names of individual nodes:

```
$serials = $child->getElementsByTagName('serial') ;
foreach($serials as $serial) {
  echo "\n" . $count++ . ", a" .$serial->nodeName ;    
}
```

As a side node, the xml in the question is not valid:

- `<displayname> ... </displayName>`
- `<vsys> <entry> ... </entry> </c>`

Comment: In my case I need to get the `serial` as a subset of its parent `entry` and keep them grouped in my output.  So I need to get each parent `entry` and iterate through its childNodes to extract `serial`, `hostname` and eventually get the each subchild `entry` contained within `vsys`.  I can't just do `getElementsByTagName(`entry')` because that is grabbing all parent and subchild `entry`.  To your side note, why is the xml not valid?  I am basically showing the exact same xml extracted for an XPath API in a router.

Comment: hmm, I wont pretend I understand how the comment applies to my answer. I'll try to rephrase it: `$serial = $child->getElementsByTagName('serial') ;` in your code is a list, which has no `nodeName` you are trying to print. If you replace this line with the snippet from my answer, you get the expected output.

Comment: now, about invalid xml. I have pointed the errors in the answer, which I believe are quite clear: opening `<displayname>` does not match closing `</displayName>`; opening `<vsys>` does not match closing `</c>`. You correctly added closing `</vsys>`, but did not remove `</c>`. Please do.

Comment: gotchya...on both.   Yes, my xml was incorrect, typos and unfinished tags (I attempted to correct a few of them).  Sorry about that.  Your explanation and solution helped me bridge the gap of what I was misunderstanding.